# Can multiple compound statements in Python be in one line?

Tags: python, python-3.x, idioms

I have some code like this:

```
def loongFunction(*args):
    if len(args) < 2:
        return
    else:
        x1 = args[0]
        y1 = args[1]
        if len(args) == 4:
            x2 = args[2]
            y2 = args[3]
```

What is the smallest / idiomatic this function can get?

Note: If `len(args)` is 2, I don't want `x2` and `y2` to be declared.

Comment: The assignments can be shortened to `x1, y1 = args[:2]` and `x2, y2 = args[2:4]`

Comment: Since the function doesn't actually do anything, the simplest would be to just pass. `def noop(*args): pass`

Comment: @HåkenLid The function does do something. I just omitted it for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want it to be as short as possible here are few tweaks you could make

```
def loongFunction(*args):
    if len(args) < 2: return
    x1, y1 = args[:2]
    if len(args) == 4: x2, y2 = args[2:4]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def loongFunction(*args):
    if len(args) > 1: x1, y1 = args[0], args[1]
    if len(args) == 4: x2, y2 = args[2], args[3]
```